# How to parallelize an identical and independedly applied code on images (uniformly distributing images per core) (Goal: Speed up)

Tags: performance, parallel-processing

My goal is to speed up a task of running an image processing code on every image (taken from a microscope) independently (approximately between 400-500 images).
The basic idea is that I feed these pictures to the cloud (optimally while they are being taken) and distribute the task to the cores (1 image per core), achieving a speed up factor proportional to the number of cores, if uploading is not a bottleneck. 
I was wondering whether anyone has tried to implement such a task and whether I can have some advice on running this procedure in parallel.
I would like to point out that I have never tried to use parallel computing so any information would be most welcome.
Although I found multiprocessing, a library for python (which is the language I use), I couldn't understand the way to do it.

Thanking you in advance :)

Comment: What you describe is *embarrassingly parallel computation* and your favourite search engine will overwhelm you with resources for learning about solutions to exactly the problem you describe.  Yes, many many thousands of programmers have trodden this path before you and yes, uploading may be a significant bottleneck.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Mark. I was actually having some problems with the interactive python enviroment (anaconda) and the multiprocessing library.
Best